# JavaFX действия над элементами одного окна из другого окна

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Помогите решить проблему.
Имеются два fxml файла и их контроллеры:

```
sample.fxml, его контроллер ControllerMain (главное окно программы)
find_win.fxml, его контроллер ControllerFind (модальное окно поиска текста)
```

В модальном окне find_win.fxml имеется TextField, в который вводится искомый текст, и кнопка "Найти", при нажатии на которую ControllerFind должен обработать нажатие и вызвать метод поиска и выделения искомого текста в элементе TextArea окна sample.fxml.

`<fx:include source="sample.fxml" fx:id="textAreaOne"/>`

и унаследование ControllerMain контроллером ControllerFind не помогают добиться решения - в первом случае включается вся разметка окна в модальное окно полностью, во втором случае при операцией над TextArea возвращается `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Как правильно реализовать действия над элементами одного окна из другого окна?

Comment: передаете экземпляр первого контролера второму, а второй контроллер получает экземпляр первого контроллера и вызывает через него нужные ему методы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо комментатору Maxim за его краткий, но емкий комментарий, который указал направление в сторону верного решения. Т.к. ответ не был дан, отвечаю сам.
Отрывок кода sample.fxml:

```
<TextArea fx:id="textAreaOne" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="783.0" </TextArea>
<MenuBar nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="613.0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
<menus>
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Правка">
  <items>
        MenuItem fx:id="findMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#findAction" text="Найти">
           <accelerator>
              <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="F" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
           </accelerator>
        </MenuItem>
  </items>
</Menu>
</MenuBar>
```

Отрывок кода ControllerMain разметки sample.fxml:

```
package sample;

public class ControllerMain {

    //ссылки на контроллеры
    private ControllerFind children;  // Ссылка на контроллер окна поиска текста

    //главное окно
    @FXML
    public TextArea textAreaOne;
    @FXML
    public MenuItem findMenuItem;

    public void findAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            Stage stageFind = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML/find_win.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            stageFind.setTitle("Найти");
            stageFind.setMinHeight(200);
            stageFind.setMinWidth(150);
            stageFind.setResizable(false);
            stageFind.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stageFind.getIcons().add(new Image("image/search.png"));
            stageFind.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            stageFind.show();

            children = loader.getController(); //получаем контроллер окна find_win.fxml
            children.setParent(this);   //устанавливаем предка – этот контроллер

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ключевой момент кроется в методе findAction, а именно:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML/find_win.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
children = loader.getController(); //получаем контроллер окна find_win.fxml
children.setParent(this);   //устанавливаем предка – этот контроллер
```

После этого в контроллере разметки find_win.fxml  нужно определить метод `setParent(ControllerMain controller):`

```
package sample.Controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.Classes.DialogManager;
import sample.ControllerMain;

public class ControllerFind {

    //окно "Найти"
    @FXML public TextField searchTextField;
    @FXML public Label findTextLabel;
    @FXML public Button okTextFindButton;
    @FXML public Button cancelTextFindButton;
    private String text;
    private ControllerMain controller;

    public void setParent (ControllerMain controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public ControllerFind getThis(){
        return this;
    }

    public void initialize(){
        System.out.println("psvm");
    }

    public void textFindOkButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        text = (searchTextField.getText());
        if (text.equals("")) {
            DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Ошибка!", "Введите текст для поиска!");
        } else {
            if (controller.textAreaOne.getText() != null && !controller.textAreaOne.getText().isEmpty()) {
                int index = controller.textAreaOne.getText().indexOf(text);
                if (index == -1) {
                    DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Результат", "Искомый текст отсутствует");
                } else {
                    controller.textAreaOne.selectRange(index, index + text.length());
                }
            } else {
                DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Ошибка", "Отсутствует исходный текст");
            }
        }
    }

    public void textFindCancelButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Node source = (Node) actionEvent.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

и, конечно же, объявить

`private ControllerMain controller;`

Все, после этого можно работать с элементами контроллера MainController из ControllerFind
Код разметки find_win.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="150.0" maxWidth="400.0" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="130.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controllers.ControllerFind">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="findTextLabel" text="Введите текст для поиска:">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="40.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="searchTextField">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets left="40.0" right="40.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </TextField>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="okTextFindButton" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#textFindOkButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="OK" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="cancelTextFindButton" cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#textFindCancelButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Отмена" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```